# How to return a record set from a Function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, user-defined-types

I am trying to get the record data using function by passing values

please find the below

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
   (    "TEST_ID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TEST_DESC" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "TEST_DATE" DATE
); 

create or replace TYPE TEST_OBJ_TYPE IS OBJECT
(
TEST_ID   NUMBER(9),
TEST_DESC VARCHAR(30),
dates date
);

create or replace TYPE TEST_TABTYPE AS TABLE OF TEST_OBJ_TYPE;
```

Using the above object and table type created the function as follows

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_ROWS(dates date)RETURN TEST_TABTYPE
AS
V_Test_Tabtype Test_TabType;
table_name varchar2(30);
q1 varchar2(300);
BEGIN

            table_name :='Test';

                q1 := 'SELECT TEST_OBJ_TYPE(A.TEST_ID, A.TEST_DESC)FROM' || '
                      (SELECT TEST_ID, TEST_DESC FROM ' || table_name || ' where 
                       TEST_DATE = '''||dates||''' ) A';
            dbms_output.put_line(q1); 
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  q1  BULK COLLECT INTO V_Test_TabType ;

            RETURN V_Test_TabType;

           EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
           v_Test_TabType.DELETE;
           RETURN v_Test_TabType;
END;
```

When I execute this the SQL is printing correctly but not giving the record value.

```
Error as follows:
select (GET_ROWS('01-08-18')) from dual
Error report -
ORA-02315: incorrect number of arguments for default constructor
ORA-06512: at "AMTEL_MIS.GET_ROWS", line 13

SELECT TEST_OBJ_TYPE(A.TEST_ID, A.TEST_DESC) FROM (SELECT TEST_ID, TEST_DESC FROM Test where TEST_DATE = '01-08-18' ) A
```

Please assist me further

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you complicating your stuff. Use simply `sys_refcursor` to get the results out. No need to use dynamic SQl here

Comment: @XING - Actually, it depends how the OP intends to use the function. If they need to call it from other SQL statements then this is the correct solution. We can't use Ref Cursors in a `table()` call.

Comment: @APC I saw the execution part of OP and suggested. Ofcourse as a table operator `sys_refcursor` will not work however if you do simple select as column it will work

Answer (score 2):

Your type TEST_OBJ_TYPE is defined with **three** attributes: `TEST_ID`, `TEST_DESC`, `DATES`. However, your query populates the constructor with just two columns:

```
SELECT TEST_OBJ_TYPE(A.TEST_ID, A.TEST_DESC) FROM
```

You're missing a value for `DATES` and that's why Oracle hurls ORA-02315.

> I have tried as per your suggestion but it's is giving me an error
>   `ORA-00904: "A"."DATES": invalid identifier`

Because of the convoluted way your function is written you need to include TEST_DATE (or `dates`) in both the subquery and the object constructor:

```
 q1 := 'SELECT TEST_OBJ_TYPE(A.TEST_ID, A.TEST_DESC,A.TEST_DATE)FROM' || '  -- here!
             (SELECT TEST_ID, TEST_DESC, TEST_DATE FROM '  -- and here!
              || table_name || ' where TEST_DATE = '''||dates||''' ) A';
```

If you do that your code will work. Here is [a LiveSQL demo of your code](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/g2ccah4s0kud9cus69v1h00ae) with the fix. (Free Oracle login required).

As it seems likely that you will want to pass in the table name so here is a version of your code which does that:

```
create or replace function get_rows(dates date, p_table_name in varchar2) 
    return test_tabtype   
as   
    v_test_tabtype test_tabtype;   
    q1 varchar2(300);   
begin   

    q1 := 'select test_obj_type(a.test_id, a.test_desc,a.test_date) from' 
             || '(select test_id, test_desc, test_date from ' 
             || p_table_name 
             || ' where test_date = :1 ) a';   
    dbms_output.put_line(q1);    

    execute immediate  q1  
        bulk collect into v_test_tabtype
        using dates ;   

    return v_test_tabtype;   

exception   
     when others then   
        v_test_tabtype.delete;   
        return v_test_tabtype;   
end;
```

Note how much easier it is to understand the code when it is laid out with consistent use of case and regular indentation. Readability is a feature!

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion but it's is giving me an error `Error report -
ORA-00904: "A"."DATES": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "AMTEL_MIS.GET_ROWS", line 12
` Please assist me in this case